# Google Script equivalent of Excel VBA Refedit

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, equivalent, vba

I'm trying to replicate some Excel VBA in Google Script.  I want to prompt the user to input a range from a Google Spreadsheet.  Is there a script equivalent to refedit?  I need them to input three ranges so I can't just use the currently selected range.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Theres no equivalent. You can ask them to select them one by one by selecting them in the spreadsheet, or make a dialog that asks the user to type them on text fields.